# Can I define a receiving method in main?

Tags: go

I can define a function globally,

```golang
func f()int{
    return 0
}
```

But I can also do in main,

```golang
func main(){
    var f=func()int{
        return 0
    }
}
```

Can I do the same with receiving methods? I can do globally,

```golang
type I int
func(i I)f()int{
    return int(i)
}
```

But can I do this in main too, so like (because this does not work)

```golang
func main(){
    type I int
    var f=func(i I)()int{
        return 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not like that,
but like this working sample code you may still use `f`:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    j := I(2)
    fmt.Println(j.Double())

    f := j.Double

    fmt.Println(f())
}

type I int

func (i I) Double() int {
    return int(i) * 2
}
```

output:

```
4
4
```

Comment: Thanks. So the answer is no?